# Android 6.1 and Smartwatch not communicating WearableListenerService

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to send messages between my phone and wearable using the Wearable message API. Both the phone(physical One plus one) and the smartwatch(physical sony smartwatch 3) will connect to each other. Sending a message also reports back as sent. But neither the Mobile nor the wearable Application's WearableServiceListener will respond to these messages.

I have checked:

1. ApplicationID
2. Package Names
3. Manifest

What else can i check to find the problem?
Thank you

```
public class MainActivityPhone extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private Node connectedPhone;
private static String WEAR_PATH = "/from_phone";
private final String TAG = MainActivityPhone.class.getSimpleName();
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();

}

public void phoneButtonHandler(View view){
    sendMessage();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    Log.e(TAG,"connection suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(TAG,"connection failed");
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes) {
                    for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                        if (node != null && node.isNearby()) {
                            connectedPhone = node;
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to " + connectedPhone.getDisplayName());
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (connectedPhone == null) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "not connected!");
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

private void sendMessage(){

    if(connectedPhone != null && googleApiClient != null) {

        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleApiClient, connectedPhone.getId(), WEAR_PATH, "alarm".getBytes()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {

                Log.e(TAG, "message sent");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {

                Log.e(TAG, "connection failed!" + status.getStatusMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"failed to send, no connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

.

```
<service android:name=".ListenerFromWear">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and for both modules:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.leon_wolf.bigpresenter.connectphoneandwatch"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your service definition to be:

```
<service android:name=".ListenerFromWear">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:host="*" android:scheme="wear" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

You need to specify the `wear` scheme as detailed here:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService

Also make sure your `Service` extends `WearableListenerService`